# Calculating Betti tables of smooth curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, software

I am looking for a software that could help me calculate the Betti table of smooth curves. I was trying to use Macaulay2, but calculating Betti tables of smooth curves on that seems really hard and non-standard. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these plane curves?  How are you realizing them?

Comment: Well Betti tables of complete intersection curves are easy.  I don't know what you mean by non-standard, but Betti tables of non- complete intersection curves are hard and only incompletely understood.  For example there is the Green conjecture about the Betti table of a canonically embedded curve.  When I think of Betti tables I think of the names Ein, Lazersfeld, and Erman.  You should check out some of their papers.